# send data as a file with aiohttp

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have such endpoint which returns a file with csv:

```
# POST /export/
@asyncio.coroutine
def export(request):
    post = yield from request.post()
    if not post.get('passwd', None) == 'topsecret':
        return web.Response(status=403)

    csv = data.encode()
    resp = web.StreamResponse(headers=aiohttp.MultiDict({
        'CONTENT-DISPOSITION': 'attachment; filename="%d.csv"' % int(time.time())}))
    resp.content_type = 'text/csv'
    resp.content_length = len(csv)
    yield from resp.prepare(request)

    resp.write(csv)

    return resp
```

My question is next: is it possible to set headers automatically somehow? As the [documentation](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.org/en/stable/multipart.html) says, aiohttp has `BodyPartWriter` class which has `set_content_disposition` method. But, as far as I understood, it could be used only with the client API (or at least, there are only examples for client API).
So, is it possible to use `BodyPartWriter` with the `Response` objects?

Answer (score 1):

[`BodyPartWriter`](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api.html#aiohttp.multipart.BodyPartWriter) & [`BodyPartReader`](https://aiohttp.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api.html#aiohttp.multipart.BodyPartReader) APIs are only for reading or writing parts of a *multipart* encoded *client-side* request/response (hence, they are under the `multipart` module).

Sending a *multipart* server-side response doesn't make any sense.

In your case you are returning a response, providing `content-disposition` as a hint to the browser on how to name the file. At the moment there is no automatic way of sending a file that would also fill in the appropriate headers.